# Why unsigned int value in c bit-field became signed value?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
struct Foo 
{
    int a : 2;
    int b : 2;
    int c : 2;
    int d : 2;
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.d = 2;
    std::cout << sizeof(foo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using g++, the result turns to be `4 -2`, how could foo.d became -2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first one is sign bit.
for 2 (10) first one is sign 1 so its negative number.
2's compliment of 10 you will get -2.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is signed by default, so an `int :2` has a range of -2 through 1. Use `unsigned int :2` if you want to be able to store values 0 through 3 instead.